# Will a hash of bytes from a double always be the same for the same value?

Tags: c, hash, double, normalization

I guess my question could also be asked this way: Can a single decimal value be represented more than one way in a double precision variable.

I have a hash table implementation, double-precision floating point numbers will be the keys, and I am using a hashing algorithm that builds a hash while iterating over each byte of the double (which at least on my system is 64-bit, so 8 bytes to hash). My issue is that if a single value, say '1.2345' can be represented in binary-form in the double more than 1 way then it could result in multiple possible hash values for a single value.

I am not sure where to research this possibility. If I had to guess I would guess that it is not possible, or that if it is possible that something normalizes it to ensure a value always has the same representation on a given system. I am mainly looking for confirmation of this.

If a value can have multiple representations then I will need to normalize the value before hashing it, and I would love suggestions on how to do that.

EDIT:

I have found out a bit more about floating point numbers. They are stored as a mantessa and an exponent. So my question is can a single floating point number be represented by more than one combination of mantessa and exponent.

Comment: Use fixed point instead?

Comment: It is “mantissa”, not “mantessa”. Except it is a significand (linear), not a mantissa (logarithmic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have two problems with byte-wise hashing of floating point numbers.

The first one, which comes up surprisingly often, is that there are two representations for 0, one with each possible sign bit. (0 and negative 0.) These are not only mathematically equal, but also required to test equal in C/C++. Negative 0 shows up surprisingly often in calculations, although not all `printf`'s  print it as -0. (On Intel hardware, at least, 0.0/-1.0 is -0.0.)

So you need to make sure that both zeros hash to the same thing.

The other problem is NaNs. There are quite a lot of NaNs, but they are not comparable (technically) even to themselves, so they make lousy hash keys. Probably the simplest solution is to ignore them, because no-one should expect a NaN to be usable as a hash key. But the problem is that if someone tries to put one into your hash table, and then puts it in again, it may end up being entered twice, if you use floating point `==` to check for key presence. Consequently, a simple bug (or deliberate attack) could rapidly exhaust memory by expanding the hash table. (If you compare bytes with memcmp, you won't have this problem.)

Answer (score 2):

IEEE 754 binary floating point has exactly one encoding for each representable value except zero, for which there is a +0 and a –0.

Most C implementations today use IEEE 754 binary format. However, not all implement floating point operations correctly (e.g., conversion from decimal in a character string to binary floating point may yield a slightly inaccurate result), and the results of chains of operations may differ from the value you would get with exact arithmetic, and different chains may yield different values even though they would be identical mathematically. (This latter includes the result of compiling the same source code with different compilers that do not provide strict floating-point evaluation.)

IEEE 754 also specifies a decimal floating point format, and that does have multiple representations for values.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Double precision values are more precise than floats, but are still not 100% airtight when it comes to precision. Use fixed point or integer-pair representations (i.e.: integer for each part of the value).